# Windows.Forms - Change ImageList Bitmaps pixels for HighContrast

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, imagelist

Need help with altering the Bitmaps in an ImageList to switch the black pixels to yellow, they are being used as images for a UICommandBar (screenshot and attempt below)

[image: UICommandBar images not visible when in HighContrast]

The code gets executed, with GetPixel condition and then SetPixel, but the images are not changed. Maybe related to ImageListStreamer or not the right time to swap those pixels.

*rtfeditor.cs*

```
this.imageList1.ImageStream = ( (System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject( "imageList1.ImageStream" ) ) );

this.imageList1 = ColorSpace.ProcessHighContrast(this.imageList1);
```

*Utils\ColorSpace.cs*

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.ImageList ProcessHighContrast(System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imageList)
                 {
                         if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.HighContrast)
                         {
                                 foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap imageListImage in imageList.Images)
                                  {
                                          for (int i = 0; i < imageListImage.Width; i++)
                                          {
                                                  for (int j = 0; j < imageListImage.Height; j++)
                                                   {
                                                           Color color =     imageListImage.GetPixel(i, j);
                                                           if (System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0).Equals(color))
                                                                  imageListImage.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText);
                                                   }
                                          }
                                  }
                         }

                         return imageList;
                 }
```

Comment: ImageList.Images returns a *copy* of each image.  Altering the copy therefore does not modify the ImageList content at all.  Create a new ImageList instead.  Do consider that Darth Vader color schemes tend to be appreciated only by programmers, regular users expect the high contrast version to have a white background.  That's going to be a lot less painful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the ProcessHighContrast method to create a new ImageList and Add the Bitmaps to it after processing. Unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved***
[image]

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s comment was critical for resolving this (see quoted comment below) + changing the order of the call of ProcessHighContrast (now first) with the assignment of the ImageList to the Janus.Windows.UI.CommandBars.UICommandBar (now second). New method and calling code below.

> ImageList.Images returns a copy of each image. Altering the copy therefore does not modify the ImageList content at all. Create a new ImageList instead. Do consider that Darth Vader color schemes tend to be appreciated only by programmers, regular users expect the high contrast version to have a white background. That's going to be a lot less painful. – Hans Passant

*rtfeditor.cs*

```
        this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));

        this.imageList1 = ColorSpace.ProcessHighContrast(this.imageList1);

        this.uiCommandManager1.ImageList = this.imageList1;
```

*Utils\ColorSpace.cs*

```
        public static System.Windows.Forms.ImageList ProcessHighContrast(System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imageList)
    {
        if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.HighContrast)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imageListNew = new ImageList();

            foreach (System.Drawing.Bitmap imageListImage in imageList.Images)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < imageListImage.Width; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < imageListImage.Height; j++)
                    {
                        Color color = imageListImage.GetPixel(i, j);

                        if (System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0).Equals(color))
                            imageListImage.SetPixel(i, j, System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText);
                    }
                }

                imageListNew.Images.Add(imageListImage);
            }

            return imageListNew;
        }

        return imageList;
    }
```